Spark : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
I am working on spark streaming and reading data from kafka topic, but getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater. Running my code in K8s and provide details for the same below
Below are spark and kafka version :
I am running on K8s using minikube:
bitnami : Spark version - 3.5.1 ( 1 master and 2 worker nodes)
bitnami : Kafka version - 3.7.0 ( 3 Kafka nodes and one kafka-client)
Below is the code :
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://spark-kafka-stream-master-svc:7077") \
    .appName("KafkaSparkStructuredStreaming") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define Kafka source
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "kafka-release.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092"  # Change this to your Kafka bootstrap server
kafka_topic = "test1"  # Change this to your Kafka topic

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

# Define schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("field1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("field2", StringType(), True)
    # Add your fields here
])

# Parse Kafka messages
df_parsed = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("data")) \
    .select("data.*")

# Write stream to console
query = df_parsed \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()

Spark submit command :
kubectl exec -ti --namespace kafka spark-kafka-stream-worker-0 -- spark-submit \
                                                               --master spark://spark-kafka-stream-master-svc:7077 
                                                               --jars /tmp/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.5.1.jar,/tmp/kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar 
                                                               /tmp/testConsumer.py

Below is the error :
24/05/28 13:48:37 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 215e6995-5cf4-449c-a7e1-b1d5a4fbb83c, runId = 200cee24-aaf9-4ab9-942f-eb06044e2c60] terminated with error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.kafkaParamsForDriver(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:645)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan.toMicroBatchStream(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:482)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$4(MicroBatchExecution.scala:107)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:303)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$1(StreamExecution.scala:211)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.JobArtifactSet$.withActiveJobArtifactState(JobArtifactSet.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:211)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        ... 56 more
24/05/28 13:48:37 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Async log purge executor pool for query [id = 215e6995-5cf4-449c-a7e1-b1d5a4fbb83c, runId = 200cee24-aaf9-4ab9-942f-eb06044e2c60] has been shutdown
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = 215e6995-5cf4-449c-a7e1-b1d5a4fbb83c, runId = 200cee24-aaf9-4ab9-942f-eb06044e2c60]" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.kafkaParamsForDriver(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:645)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan.toMicroBatchStream(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:482)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$4(MicroBatchExecution.scala:107)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:303)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$1(StreamExecution.scala:211)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.JobArtifactSet$.withActiveJobArtifactState(JobArtifactSet.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:211)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        ... 56 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/testConsumer.py", line 42, in <module>
    query.awaitTermination()
  File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming/query.py", line 221, in awaitTermination
  File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = 215e6995-5cf4-449c-a7e1-b1d5a4fbb83c, runId = 200cee24-aaf9-4ab9-942f-eb06044e2c60] terminated with exception: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://spark-kafka-stream-worker-0.spark-kafka-stream-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local:4040
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend$StandaloneDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
24/05/28 13:48:38 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
24/05/28 13:48:39 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
24/05/28 13:48:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/05/28 13:48:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3a1f6ff0-a0e3-4e3c-8570-203ffea6172d
24/05/28 13:48:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3a1f6ff0-a0e3-4e3c-8570-203ffea6172d/pyspark-71dcc231-7168-454b-a1c1-af5871e2cbee
24/05/28 13:48:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-6f2f84ca-5c84-4eeb-ad2c-3516dd766683
24/05/28 13:48:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/temporary-59173a93-3a45-4e26-a411-4e0c1d8157b2
command terminated with exit code 1

